# Why am I getting "Your browser does not support iframes" in multiple browsers?

Tags: theming

I want to display a third party page within my theme and thought an `<iframe>` should do. However, I added the `<iframe>` to my basic page, selecting`Full HTML` but all I'm getting is `Your browser does not support iframes` with multiple browsers while I can use the iframe on the [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe) website just fine. Why is this?

The link: http://spabc.com/drupal/content/store

Comment: Weird, I've never had any problems using iframes on drupal. Have you tried browsing your site on a different computer? Does this happen on a fresh Drupal install? maybe there is a module or template file that's creating this conflict.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yeah, I've tried on another computer too, same thing. Here's the link: http://spabc.com/drupal/content/store

Comment: oh yes, I get the message too. Can you switch to a default drupal theme, like bartik, and check if it fixes? If it does we can conclude that its your theme and you would need to check the themes template files.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, I've tried to temporarily switch to Bartik and got the same message...

Comment: On your field what text format are you using? Text, Filter HTML or Full HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it's because I'm using CKEditor.

When editing the page, I had to click on **Switch to plain text editor** in order to get the iframe to load. CKEditor would convert that HTML into a misleading string of **Your browser does not support iframes**.

Comment: Were you using filter html? because by default filter html doesn't support the iframe tag, you have to add `<iframe>` in admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html under Limit Allowed HTML Tags

Comment: @NoSssweat No, I was using the `Full HTML` filter